# Create a node set in Abaqus programatically (python scripting)

Tags: python, scripting, set, nodes, abaqus

I would appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm missing. I'm trying to create a geometry-dependent set of nodes from a merged instance part. Once  generated the geometry, the instances, merged and meshed the resulting part, the code reads:

```
all_nodes = model_assembly.instances[merged_part_instance_name].nodes
left_nodes = []
bottom_nodes = []
for n in all_nodes:
    xcoord = n.coordinates[0]
    ycoord = n.coordinates[1]
    if xcoord > xmin and xcoord < xmax:
        left_nodes.append(n)
    if ycoord > ymin and ycoord < ymax:
        bottom_nodes.append(n)
```

With the code above, I have a list of `'MeshNode objects'`, so writing this works fine:

```
model_assembly.Set(nodes=all_nodes, name='Set-all')
```

However, when I write:

```
model_assembly.Set(nodes=left_nodes, name='Set-left')
```

it gives me the error `Feature creation failed.`
I checked in the CAE console, and both `all_nodes[0]` and `left_nodes[0]` have the same structure:

```
mdb.models['mymodel'].rootAssembly.instances['merged_part_instance'].nodes[x] # x may differ
```

Nonetheless, I noticed that printing the lists gave different results:

```
>>>print(all_nodes)
['MeshNode object', 'MeshNode object', ...

>>> print(left_nodes)
[mdb.models['mymodel'].rootAssembly.instances['merged_part_instance'].nodes[57], mdb.models['mymodel'].rootAssembly.instances['merged_part_instance'].nodes[59],...
```

So, why are they different? Can I fix it or there is a better way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `assembly.Set` method needs specifically a `MeshNodeArray` as input, so doing this solved my problem:

```
good_left_nodes = mesh.MeshNodeArray(left_nodes)
model_assembly.Set(nodes=good_left_nodes , name='Set-left')
```